# How can i get multiple documents from the firestore

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I want to get multiple documents from the firestore.

```
var docBookingRef = firestore().collection('timeSlot');
docData.forEach((item) => {
    docBookingRef.where('docId', '==', item);
});
docBookingRef.get().then((doc) => {
    doc.forEach(function(docV) {
        console.log("Slot data", docV.data());

    });
})
```

docData contains ids of all list.
I am not getting any list from the above code.

Answer (score 2):

I have barely used React and never used Firebase, but after using a `where` you might inmediately want to use the `get()` (`where` returns a new query object and the `get()` retrieves the info, as [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) clarified)

```
docData.forEach((item)=>{
   firestore().collection('timeSlot')
              .where('docId','==', item)
              .get()
              .then(function(doc) {
                     doc.forEach(function(docV) {
                         console.log("Slot data", docV.data());
                     });
              });
});
```

Comment: Almost! The `where(...)` call returns a new `Query` object, so you'll want to do `docBookingRef.where('docId','==',item).get().then(...`.

Comment: I have problem with this it always sends me same data. Slot data alwats same not different

Comment: @SShah does **the exact piece of code of the answer** (correcting typos, if there is any) print always the same data on the console? If that is the case, then the problem might be somewhere else